# Copying Object Attributes with Ruby On Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm copying a object attributes from a Model to another model like this;

```
 @estimate = Estimate.find(params[:estimate_id])
 @invoice = Invoice.create(@estimate.attributes)
```

With this copy, its just copies model attributes only, 
(Estimate copies as new Invoice) but Estimate model and Invoice model has HABTM relation with "Item" model.

How to create new @invoice object with Estimate and it's Item's together? Confused...

**Update:**

- Estimate : has_and_belongs_to_many :items (estimates_items table)
            accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
- Invoice  : has_and_belongs_to_many :items (invoices_items table)
            accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
- Item     : belongs_to :estimate 
            belongs_to :invoice

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're meaning here. Are you wanting to both copy the attrs and create a record in the join table to associate the two at the same time? If so this should do the trick I think (untested)...

```
@estimate = Estimate.find(params[:estimate_id])
@invoice = Invoice.create(@estimate.attributes.merge(:items => @estimate.items))
```

Comment: Yes. Estimate copy as Invoice "clone" with Item attributes. Item model is HABTM association with Estimate and Invoice. Tested this code. It returns "unknown attribute: estimates". Looks like problem comes from nested attrs

Comment: Sorry, I thought Invoice habtm :estimates. Can you add the relations between the models to your question?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use "items" instead. On a side note, if Item only belongs_to estimate and invoice, what's the point in using habtm here?

Comment: Tested with your new update and it works. Yes, its habtm. I'm bit confused with relations. Thanks for your help.